# Word 2013 showing two pages side by side

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

All of a sudden Word started displaying 2 pages side by side in one window. I tried changing the zoom and it didn't affect anything. How can I go back to seeing 1 page at a time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To view a single page at a time, select the `View` tab on the ribbon and click `One Page`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know how it got changed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that good. It could have something to do with the saved file you are opening and the display settings. I know mine changes because I have a wide monitor, so when I maximize my document there is more working area in Word to display pages. Just a guess. Feel free to check this as your answer if it was correct.

Comment: The Word document I was working on is on a USB stick so it could have to do with change in monitor size.

Comment: Note, this does not fix the print preview

Comment: This only works until I touch the zoom slider or `+`/`−` buttons. I have to zoom using `Ctrl`+mouse scroll.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the zoom size. I solved this by setting the default zoom to 120%, and then only a single page is displayed by default.

To set it to 120% by default, you'd need to add a macro:

1. When viewing any Word document, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to activate the Visual Basic Editor
2. Click on **Normal** on the left hand side
3. Select **Insert** -> **Module**
4. Copy the following code into the module:

   ```
   Sub AutoNew()
       With ActiveWindow.View
          .Type = wdPrintView
          .Zoom = 120
       End With
   End Sub

   Sub AutoOpen()
       With ActiveWindow.View
           .Type = wdPrintView
           .Zoom = 120
      End With
   End Sub
   ```

This will set the zoom percentage to 120% for every new document and for every document that you open. You can change 120 to another percentage if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in print view change to layout view then back to print view.  This should reset back to a view of one page only.